# Laravel-Excel throwing exception when download as .xls

Tags: php, laravel, xls, laravel-excel

I'm using maatwebsite/laravel-excel package to handle a very simple report generator. The following code is throwing an exception with the error `'Call to a member function setExtSheet() on null'  in xxx/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Workbook.php:232`.

```
    Excel::create($filename, function ($excel) use ($reportData) {

        $excel->sheet('Sheet1', function ($sheet) use ($reportData) {

            $sheet->fromArray($reportData, null, 'A1', false, false);

        });

    })->export('xls');
```

The strange thing is that it works *perfectly* when I use `->export('xlsx')` or `->export('csv')`. It's only erroring when I use `->export('xls')`.

Comment: are you using the latest version of `maatwebsite/laravel-excel` ?

Comment: yep, v2.1.2 https://packagist.org/packages/maatwebsite/excel

Comment: what is your MS excel version?? Export to Excel5 (xls), Export to Excel2007 (xlsx)